# Pyspark: Combine multiple columns into an Array of Strings with column names

Tags: pyspark

I'm attempting to append multiple columns into a single column as seen below:

Input

```
A  | B  | C  | D  | E
aa | bb | cc | dd | null
```

Output

```
A  | B  | C  | D  | E    | combine
aa | bb | cc | dd | null | [A: aa, B: bb, C: cc, D: dd, E: null]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the array of string, you need to fill the null and concat the string:

```
df.fillna(
    'null'
).withColumn(
    'combine',
    func.array([func.concat_ws(': ', col, val) for col, val in [(func.lit(col), func.col(col)) for col in df.columns]])
).show(1, False)
+---+---+---+---+----+-------------------------------------+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |E   |combine                              |
+---+---+---+---+----+-------------------------------------+
|aa |bb |cc |dd |null|[A: aa, B: bb, C: cc, D: dd, E: null]|
+---+---+---+---+----+-------------------------------------+
```